# Amazon Turk - How secure is it? Strange behavior

Tags: passwords, authentication, web-application

I just had this really strange experience with Amazon Turk, where suddenly I was logged into someone else's account. I was logged into the company's Turk account, left my computer for a while, refreshed the tab and BOOM, someone else's account.

Does anyone have a clue what this could be? It was a real person, a real account, I saw all of their information. It's possible that someone who has access to this account also has access to the account I saw (not sure yet), but that shouldn't affect me, right?

Bug in AWS? Problem on my end? I've been looking for the solution now for about 20 minutes couldn't find a thing.

How is this possible? Should I be worried?

Comment: I don't know that anybody outside of Amazon will be able to answer this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and figured it out. I'm using a client's AWS account and was not aware of how they set up the IAM. Apparently, it's the cross-account access settings that caused this. It was set up a long time ago and nobody really bothered to tell me how it was set up, nor do I think they really payed much attention...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/delegation-cross-acct-access.html

So I learned my lesson here and will never assume things when using an a client's AWS account.